# PowerShell RegEx with multiple options

Tags: regex, powershell

Given a file name of `22-PLUMB-CLR-RECTANGULAR.0001.rfa` I need a RegEx to match it. Basically it's any possible characters, then . and 4 digits and one of four possible file extensions.
I tried `^.?\.\d{4}\.(rvt|rfa|rte|rft)$` , which I would have thought would be correct, but I guess my RegEx understanding has not progressed as much as I thought/hoped. Now, `.?\.\d{4}\.(rvt|rfa|rte|rft)$` does work and the ONLY difference is that I am not specifying the start of the string with ^. In a different situation where the file name is always in the form `journal.####.txt` I used `^journal\.\d{4}\.txt$` and it matched `journal.0001.txt` like a champ. Obviously when I am specifying a specific string, not any characters with .? is the difference, but I don't understand the WHY.

Comment: You probably meant `^.*` by showing `^.?`.

Comment: or maybe `^[^\.]*`

Comment: ^.* works just fine. Maybe it is what the OP is looking for

Comment: Huzzah! That's it @revo. But, what is the difference between .* and .? ? I thought .? was any character, any number of times.

Comment: @Gordon I made it an answer below.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Could be but chances are it couldn't since OP states *any possible characters*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That never matches the mentioned string since `^.?` means match beginning of input string then one optional single character. Then it looks for a sequence of dots and digits and nothing's there. Because we didn't yet pass the first character.

Why does it work without `^`? Because without `^` it is allowed to go through all characters to find a match and it stops right before `R` and continues matching up to the end.

That's fine but with first approach it should be `^.*`. Kleene star matches every thing greedily then backtracks but `?` is the operator here which makes preceding pattern optional. That means one character, not many characters.